# Enum <-> String comparison in JAVA

Tags: java, string, enums, compare

I want to compare a `String` with an `Enum`. I know how to do the comparison properly but i don't understand exactly why. My following example shows my issue:

```
enum Foo{
    TEST1
}

String likeEnumTest1 = "TEST1";
System.out.println("Is enum equal string?: " + likeEnumTest1.equals(Foo.TEST1));
System.out.println("Is enum.toString() equal string?: " + likeEnumTest1.equals(Foo.TEST1.toString()));
System.out.println("Value of enum '" + Foo.TEST1 + "' and value of string '" + likeEnumTest1+"'");
```

The output is:

> Is enum equal string?: false
>   Is enum.toString() equal string?: true
>   Value of enum 'TEST1' and value of string 'TEST1'

I understand that `Enum.toString()` is called implicit when using it in `System.println()`, but i don't understand what the `Enum` uses as value when compared with `equals()` in the second line. Is `Foo.TEST1` used as `Integer` or anything else, what does `JAVA` do internally?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`String#equals(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method first checks if the passed argument is an instance of `String` or not. Here's a snippet of the source code:

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        // Code [...]
    }
    return false;
}
```

Since `Foo.TEST1` is not an instance of `String`, it returns `false`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, now i understand the equal method for my case

Answer (score 3):

> Q. I want to compare a String with an Enum

[Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) provides a [`name()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name%28%29) method. You need to use that to be able to compare a `enum` object with a `String` because the `equals()` method checks if the argument is a `String` instance or not. And since it is not, it'd would return `false`.

```
likeEnumTest1.equals(Foo.TEST1.name())
```

This can be seen from the [source code of equals() of String class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) { // It takes an object and even enum is an object, thus it doesn't call the `toString()` method.
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String)anObject;
        int n = count;
        if (n == anotherString.count) {
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = offset;
            int j = anotherString.offset;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```